# Mutually exclusive selects/dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create mutually exclusive dropdowns using JS.

Only one OS can be selected from these 4: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSoB7.png)

When one is selected, the others should be disabled.

HTML part:

```
<table id="table_os" class="table table-bordered">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td class="text-center">
        <div><img src="distro-redhat.png"></div>
        <div><h6><span class="semi-bold">Red Hat Linux</span></h6></div>
        <select class="form-control" style="text-align-last: center;">
            <option value="" selected disabled>Select version</option>
            <option value="rhel7">7 (latest) </option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
        <div><img src="oel.png"></div>
        <div><h6><span class="semi-bold">Oracle Linux</span></h6></div>
        <select class="form-control" style="text-align-last: center;">
            <option value="" selected disabled>Select version</option>
            <option value="oel7">7 (latest)</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
        <div><img src="centos.png"></div>
        <div><h6><span class="semi-bold">CentOS Linux</span></h6></div>
        <select class="form-control" style="text-align-last: center;">
            <option value="" selected disabled>Select version</option>
            <option value="centos7">7 (latest)</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
        <div><img src="windows.png"></div>
        <div><h6><span class="semi-bold">Microsoft Windows</span></h6></div>
        <select class="form-control" style="text-align-last: center;">
            <option value="" selected disabled>Select version</option>
            <option value="win2012r2">Standard 2012 R2</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Asking for help for the JS part.

UPDATE: Perhaps, I misled everyone by saying "others should be disabled". Naturally, it should be possible to select any of the values but in such a way that only one is selected at all times. For instance: currently, I select Red Hat > 7 and the others get disabled. But now if I want to select Oracle Linux > 7, I should be allowed to do so. Meaning that the other dropdowns should "reset" to "Select version"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by listening to the `change` event of the `<select>` elements then utilizing jQuery `not()` to target other `<select>` elements:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $table = $('#table_os');

  $table.find('select').on('change', function() {
    var val = $(this).val();

    if (val !== '') {
      $(this).closest('tr').find('select').not($(this)).prop('disabled', true);
    }
  });
});
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5yppd9ac/1/) demonstrating the functionality.

As the first `<option>` of each select is disabled due to HTML `disabled` property you have in your provided markup, once they have been disabled they will remain that way.

If you remove the `disabled` property on the default/first `<option>` of each `<select>` you can easily build functionality to re-enable other dropdowns if the user selects this default/first option in case they change their mind. Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hmywwwab/2/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $table = $('#table_os')

  $table.find('select').on('change', function(){
    var val = $(this).val();

    var $otherSelects = $(this).closest('tr').find('select').not($(this));

    if(val !== '') {
        $otherSelects.prop('disabled', true);
    }
    else {
        $otherSelects.prop('disabled', false);
    }
  });
});
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: This is great - thanks! But perhaps, I misled everyone by saying "others should be disabled". Naturally, it should be possible to select any of the values but in such a way that only one is selected at all times. For instance: currently, I select Red Hat > 7 and the others get disabled. But now if I want to select Oracle Linux > 7, I should be allowed to do so. Meaning that the other dropdowns should "reset" to "Select version"

Comment: Check this out [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hmywwwab/6/). It's reverts options back to the default option (changed value of default option from empty string to -1). Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Add function to each select box and `onchange` call function to disable rest of select elements

```js
function selectThis(obj){
var selectelems=document.getElementsByTagName('select')
for(var i=0;i<selectelems.length;i++){
 if(selectelems[i]!=obj){
    selectelems[i].setAttribute('disabled','true')
  }
}
}
```

```html
<table id="table_os" class="table table-bordered">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td class="text-center">
        <div><img src="https://www.haskell.org/platform/img/distro-redhat.svg" width="60px"></div>
        <div><h6><span class="semi-bold">Red Hat Linux</span></h6></div>
        <select class="form-control" style="text-align-last: center;" onchange="selectThis(this)">
            <option value="" selected >Select version</option>
            <option value="rhel7">7 (latest) </option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
        <div><img src="http://austinlinux.com/local/Oracle%20Linux.jpg" width="51px"></div>
        <div><h6><span class="semi-bold">Oracle Linux</span></h6></div>
        <select class="form-control" style="text-align-last: center;" onchange="selectThis(this)">
            <option value="" selected >Select version</option>
            <option value="oel7">7 (latest)</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
        <div><img src="http://seeklogo.com/images/C/centos-logo-494F57D973-seeklogo.com.png" width="60px"></div>
        <div><h6><span class="semi-bold">CentOS Linux</span></h6></div>
        <select class="form-control" style="text-align-last: center;" onchange="selectThis(this)">
            <option value="" selected >Select version</option>
            <option value="centos7">7 (latest)</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
        <div><img src="https://images.seeklogo.net/2012/12/windows-8-icon-logo-vector-400x400.png" width="60px"></div>
        <div><h6><span class="semi-bold">Microsoft Windows</span></h6></div>
        <select class="form-control" style="text-align-last: center;" onchange="selectThis(this)">
            <option value="" selected >Select version</option>
            <option value="win2012r2">Standard 2012 R2</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
$('select').on('change',function(){
     $(this).parents('tr').siblings('tr').find('select').not($(this)).prop('disabled', true);
});
```